# Does changing the compileSdkVersion affect the behavior of the app at runtime?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-build

So I know that `compileSdkVersion` is the version of the API the app is compiled against. While `targetSdkVersion` is the version the app was tested against.

I am using a library which requires some attributes present in a higher API version for which I need to update the `compileSdkVersion` else I get build errors. But I don't want to update the version of the support libraries or the targetSdkVersion. Will this have an impact on how the other features of the app behave? Can I expect to release the app with surety that other features won't break?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Will this have an impact on how the other features of the app behave?

It could only impact on a library, which wants higher API. At runtime you could check version API and skip some operations, but your case inside a box (lib), no way. However, some of classes could be deprecated or even erased in the next releases of android support library.

Iak Lake wrote a good topic about `compileSdkVersion` vs `minSdkVersion` vs `targetSdkVersion`. [Here is a link](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/picking-your-compilesdkversion-minsdkversion-targetsdkversion-a098a0341ebd).

Comment: Thanks, that link was very useful