# androidx.appcompat versions and their compatibility with android sdk versions

Tags: android, version, compatibility, androidx

I have updated the `androidx.appcompat:appcompat` library and I have found a compatibility error of this library with my android sdk version.

I am using android sdk version 30 and the latest version of appcompat needs android sdk version 33. I could only find this information with the compilation error and my question is in which web, md file, git repository etc can I find the corresponding relation between the androidx library versions and their corresponding android sdk versions?

Comment: I don't think there's any such place. However there is no reason not to use the latest compileSdk, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54315295/does-changing-the-compilesdkversion-affect-the-behavior-of-the-app-at-runtime) or [this article](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/picking-your-compilesdkversion-minsdkversion-targetsdkversion-a098a0341ebd)